# Passing arguments to Java class used in @JsonSerialize and @JsonDeserialize

Tags: java, serialization, jackson

I have a scenario which I am not sure how to google, so I'd open a question myself. If its a duplicate please link it here so I can give that question credit.

Anyway,

I have a Java Object with fields that I have the following annotations:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
@JSonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
private Date systemDate;
```

The business dictates that certain `systemDate` values in different database have different time zones (not sure why they did not standardize to UTC).

Here is an example of my `CustomSerializer.java`:

```
@Override
public void serialize(Date, value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider arg2) throws IOException {
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
    formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("CET"));
    if (value == null) {
        gen.writeNull();
    } else {
        gen.writeString(formatter.formate(value.getTime()));
    }
}
```

Instead of creating a new serializer class per timezone, is there a way to pass the timezone argument(s) to this class (and also my `Deserializer` class)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a custom annotation as below:

```java
@Target({ ElementType.FIELD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@JacksonAnnotation
public @interface DateSerialize {
    String timeZone();
}
```

Now in the field `systemDate` add this new annotation by passing the timezone

```java
@DateSerialize(timeZone = "UTC")
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
@JSonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
private Date systemDate;
```

Your serializer class should implement `ContextualSerializer` this would allow us to get the `BeanProperty` from where we could get the annotation details.

```java
public class DateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> implements ContextualSerializer {
    String timeZone;

    public DateSerializer() {
        this("UTC");
    }    
    
    public DateSerializer(String tz) {
        timeZone = tz;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZone));
        if (value == null) {
            gen.writeNull();
        } else {
            gen.writeString(formatter.format(value.getTime()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> createContextual(SerializerProvider prov, BeanProperty property) throws JsonMappingException { 
        DateSerialize annotation = property.getAnnotation(DateSerialize.class);
        String tz = (annotation == null) ? "UTC" : annotation.timeZone();   
        return new DateSerializer(tz);
    }
}
```

Similarly you could create a deserializer by implementing `ContextualDeserializer`.

Comment: I was trying to implement your solution, but I forgot to mention that my DateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>. Therefore the super(t) and the super(Date.class) does not work.

Comment: @AKJ it would still work (after removing those constructors) even if you extend `JsonSerializer`. I have updated the answer. Anyway the `StdSerializer` extends `JsonSerializer`

Comment: it is not working, it still picks up my local system time and not UTC.

Comment: @AKJ did you try to debug the code in `createContextual` and `serialize` to see if the time is getting formatted?